# Unable to complete Touch ID enrollment in MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

I am unable to complete Touch ID enrollment on my two MacBook Pros 2017.
I have replaced the entire body on both of then and haven't remove Touch ID. I now remove Touch ID on both Macs and apply to them the original Touch ID. But it's working on none of them, it says :

> Unable to complete Touch ID enrollment